# excepción en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

estoy tratando de cachar una excepción y lo hago pero después cuando quiero que siga ejecutándose el programa no lo hace. esto es lo que estoy ocupando

```
    try:
        file = open('P_XXXXXX_XXX_XX_XXXXXXX_00000000_00000000_XXXXX_XXX_XXXX_XXXX_X_XXXXXX_XXXX_XXX.pdf', 'rb')
       print('imagen encontrada') 
      break 
    except(OSError):
     pass
```

En este escenario la imagen no existe por lo que manda la excepción pero deberia de continuar con el print pero no lo hace.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

saludos!

Comment: ¿Por que tienes ese `break` ahi? ¿Tienes el `try-except` dentro de un ciclo? Con lo que tienes (errores de identación aparte) si la imagen no se encuentra no imprime nada, solo imprime cuando la encuentre.

Comment: El try-except si esta dentro de un ciclo, y entonces por lo que entiendo en caso de cachar una excepcion tendria que poner abajo del except lo que quiero que haga, en este caso el print, cierto?

Comment: Efectivamente, he dejado una respuesta con un ejemplo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que cada vez que capture una excepción imprima algo y continue debes colocarlo en el `except`, un ejemplo con su uso dentro de un ciclo:

```
for intento in range(100):
    try:
        file = open('P_XXXXXX_XXX_XX_XXXXXXX_00000000_00000000_XXXXX_XXX_XXXX_XXXX_X_XXXXXX_XXXX_XXX.pdf', 'rb')
        print('Imagen encontrada') 
        break 
    except(OSError):
        print('Falló el intento {}.'.format(intento+1))
```

en el `except`, por ejemplo, puedes hacer que imprima algo como 'La imagen x no se encontró' por cada ruta no encontrada.